# What would be the membrane's form if phospholipid tail lengths vary?

Tags: biophysics, cell-membrane

I was trying to visualize and draw the situation if the membrane lipid chain length varies.

I assume so many possible conditions if in a membrane some taller or shorter components mixed:

Such as:

[image]

etc.

But which one of this is correct? or all / some from them could be applicable?

Comment: It's difficult to judge cartoons when the molecules they represent are much more complex, however I'd say that as a general principle you never want the polar head group to enter the hydrophobic region, which happens in your pictures wherever the heads are misaligned.

Comment: Cartoon (better 'visual abbreviation') would occupy similar volumes as real molecules. As well as lipid tails would be able to bend because of conformational rotations (as seen in eclipsed and staggered forms of Ethane etc hydrocarbons)

Comment: Check out lipid rafts.

Comment: lipid rafts are complex structure with cholesterol and proteins. But I'm asking about phospholipid bilayer

Comment: As a starting point, check out the Wiki article on hydrophobic mismatch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobic_mismatch - they discuss this for proteins, but many of the same things happen for lipids. Also check out the membrane microdomain literature - people do lots of studies on simple lipid/lipid coexistence, say: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349505731817 and citations within discuss this quite a bit, though it's a very physics-heavy approach. (A review that covers some of this is: http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.biophys.36.040306.132643 )

Answer (score 1):

Some the scenarios depicted are not energetically favorable and will lead to very unstable membranes if at all.

In the presence of many short-chain lipids, where the difference in chain lengths is very drastic, it will become more favorable for the membrane to reorientate some of the short-chain lipids such that the hydrophobic gaps/pores in your cartoons convert into hydrophilic ones with the head groups forming the pore walls (see fig. below).

[image]

If the difference in chain length between the two lipids is not much, the bilayer will adjust its thickness to minimize the hydrophobic mismatch. In such cases, the bilayer will be thinner in some regions. The possibility of interdigitated bilayers is also very much there and will depend on the choice of lipids in question. Interdigitated lipid membranes have been reported before and you can look it up.

Comment: Great answer overall. I would recommend adding some references though.